# ubuntu 18.04.1 in paralles desktop on mac arrowkey down and up Abnormal

Tags: macos, ubuntu-18.04, desktop-application, parallels, arrow-keys

When I use vscode or notepad, I want to use the key arrow up and down the button to jump to the up line or the next line, but when I press the two buttons cursor will jump to the article at the beginning of the character rather than previous line！

It's really upsetting me. Help me. I've got a headache over this

1. environment：macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2)，Parallels desktop 15，Ubuntu 18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

update your parallels version 17 it fix the key arrow in some case or in setting on customise your keys in keyboard options in paralles